# In long run,Proportion of time in each state?

Tags: markov-process

Consider a homogeneous Markov Chain with transition probability matrix

```
P=

  Row 1=[0.5 0.4 0.1]
  Row 2=[0.3 0.4 0.3]
  Row 3=[0.2 0.3 0.5]
```

In the long run what is the proportion of time is process in each of the three states.

Also find closed sets in homogeneous markov chain having state space S={1,2,...,M} and determine nature of each state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is for some homework problem so the following leaves you some work.

For the first part, you're looking for some distribution of probabilities that remains constant in the long run. This vector of probabilities, $\pi$ is called the stationary distribution and its very important in Markov Chain theory. If your Markov Chain is $P$ then you're looking for $\pi$, such that $\pi\times P = \pi$. In other words:

[image]

Also note that $\sum_{i=1}^{3} \pi_{i}$ = 1. You'll need to use this fact when solving the above linear system of equations because otherwise its overdetermined and you won't be able to solve it.

Now, there's a faster way to solve for $\pi$ that requires inverting a matrix, but I'd recommend doing it this way a few times to get the hang of it before taking short cuts.

The second part of the question is a bit unclear to me. This MC has 3 states, {1,2,3} and each one is recurrent, therefore closed and irreducible. But this seems obvious in this case. Is there another MC in question?

**Edited**

I assume that you're looking for recurrent or transient states. You gave two examples. You should probably figure them out yourself, but the basic idea is to see where states communicate with each other and how - is it one way or two ways? For example:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
0.2 & 0.8 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

In this case, State 1 is an absorbing state - when you enter it, you never get out. We say it's recurrent. States 2 and 3 communicate with each other. They go back and forth forever. Together, they are recurrent. State 4 goes to State 1 and State 2. When it goes to 1, it stays there forever. When it goes to State 2, it bounces between State 2 and 3 forever. Regardless of where State 4 goes, it will never return. Therefore we call State 4 transient. Note that the probabilities don't matter for determining the nature of a state, so long as its > 0.

I'd google around for definitions of closed, reducible set and periodicity. These are more formal conditions to determine recurrence vs transience.

Answer (score -1):

For 2nd part suppose this P

Row1=[0 0 1 0]
Row2=[1 0 0 0]
Row3=[0.3 0.7 0 0]
Row4=[0.6 0.2 0.2 0]

Another P is, which i cannot understand

Row1=[0.2 0.3 0.5 0 0 0]
Row2=[0.7 0.3 0 0 0 0]
Row3=[0 1 0 0 0 0]
Row4=[0 0 0 0 0.4 0.6]
Row5=[0 0 0 0 1 0]